# How could I load dex file dynamically as byte array in Android 5.0 or above?

Tags: android-ndk, android-5.0-lollipop, dex, cracking

I have a question about loading dex files in Android 5.0 or above. As we know, in android 4.x, we can load dex files as byte array by means of native method "Dalvik_dalvik_system_DexFile_openDexFile_bytearray" in davilk/vm/native/dalvik_system_DexFile.cpp. However, in android 5.0 or above, google has changed the virtual machine from dalvik to art. How could I do this in android 5.0 or above?

Comment: http://2013.hackitoergosum.org/presentations/Day1-05.Nifty%20stuff%20that%20you%20can%20still%20do%20with%20Android%20by%20Xavier%20Martin.pdf   ------>this is the solutions for android 4.x.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but what's wrong with DexClassLoader? (https://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.html). I assume you could use it to then call methods via reflection.